# Circular const, let declaration for graph ... how to fix?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, scope, hoisting

OK, brain freeze ... I need help making this work:

```js
const a = {
  val: 'a',
  neighbor: d
}

const b = {
  val: 'b',
  neighbor: a
}

const c = {
  val: 'c',
  neighbor: b
}

const d = {
  val: 'd',
  neighbor: c
}

console.log('d: neighbor - > ', d.neighbor)
console.log('a: neighbor - > ', a.neighbor)
```

*const a* has to point to *const d*  but unfortunately *const d* is defined after *const a*. In most cases, I can move const a to be defined after *const d* but in this case *const d* needs to be defined after *const c*. What am I missing....? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `neighbor` properties as getters. A [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) is actually a function which is executed when you're retrieving the value of an object, i.e. at that point all the referred objects are already defined. This way you can also protect the `neighbor` property against accidental changes.

```js
const a = {
    val: 'a',
    get neighbor () {return d;}
};
const b = {
    val: 'b',
    get neighbor () {return a;}
};
const c = {
    val: 'c',
    get neighbor () {return b;}
};
const d = {
    val: 'd',
    get neighbor () {return c;}
};

console.log('d: neighbor - > ' , d.neighbor);
console.log('a: neighbor - > ' , a.neighbor);
```

Answer (score 3):

Declare all the objects *without* the "neighbor" property, and then add that later in separate assignments.

```
const a = {
    val: 'a'
}

const b = {
    val: 'b'
}


const c = {
    val: 'c'
}

const d = {
    val: 'd'
}

a.neighbor = d;
b.neighbor = a;
c.neighbor = b;
d.neighbor = c;
```

Comment: Alternatively you could define `neighbor`s as getters in the original object definitions.

Comment: @Teemu chop wood, carry water :)

Comment: All the time, how is that related?

Comment: It's a Buddhist saying that I've always thought of as meaning "walk before you run", but the answer on the Buddhism stackexchange disagrees with me. I am absolutely not wading into that one.